# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.coerce

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, el

I am using **javax.faces-2.2.9.jar** on **websphere 8.5** on cluster environment, and in my web.xml I have the `<distributable />` tag and also the **ClientSideSecretKey** :

```
<env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>jsf/ClientSideSecretKey</env-entry-name> 
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>somekeyhere</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>
```

I am using **jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar** :

```
<context-param>     
      <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
      <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
    </context-param>
```

**1- my session bean :**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "mySessionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {

}
```

**2- my view bean :**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myViewBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyViewBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{mySessionBean}")
    private MySessionBean mySessionBean;

}
```

**My application works fine most of the time**, but sometimes I see in the log file the following exception which I don't know the reason for it:

```
Unable to set property mySessionBean for managed bean myViewBean                                com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to set property mySessionBean for managed bean myViewBean
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder$BakedBeanProperty.set(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:44)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:34)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:95)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.PostprocessorFilter.doFilter(PostprocessorFilter.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ContainerBasedFilter.doFilter(ContainerBasedFilter.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.PreprocessorFilter.doFilter(PreprocessorFilter.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.SecurityPluginFilter.doFilter(SecurityPluginFilter.java:202)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at gov.myapp.web.filter.CoordinatorSecurityFilter.doFilter(CoordinatorSecurityFilter.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.dataserve.common.CompatibleFilter.doFilter(CompatibleFilter.java:53)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3901)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.coerce(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder$Expression.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    ... 75 more

[10/25/18 18:19:20:341 AST] 00000243 PrimeExceptio E   <Null Message>
                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.coerce(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder$Expression.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder$BakedBeanProperty.set(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:44)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:34)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:95)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.PostprocessorFilter.doFilter(PostprocessorFilter.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ContainerBasedFilter.doFilter(ContainerBasedFilter.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.PreprocessorFilter.doFilter(PreprocessorFilter.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.SecurityPluginFilter.doFilter(SecurityPluginFilter.java:202)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at gov.myapp.web.filter.CoordinatorSecurityFilter.doFilter(CoordinatorSecurityFilter.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.dataserve.common.CompatibleFilter.doFilter(CompatibleFilter.java:53)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3901)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
```

I want to know if this is a bug or configuration error or it's normal due to session expire ?

Comment: You know there are newer EL versions do you?

Comment: @Kukeltje,so is it an EL issue ? the thing is that i am working on old production system and upgrade is not really easy option for me, but if i have to i will

Comment: i have a limitation that i am working on Java 6 and java upgrade is not an option

Comment: No not specifically EL, but I noticed th old vesion number. If it happens occasionally, there is a chance that for one reason or another the bean to be injected cannot be created (error in constructor or something)

Comment: Doesn't websphere deliver its' own EL implementation? I remember we had plenty of sporadic [Nullpointer]Exceptions in old EL implementations in the past.

Comment: @Kukeltje, any ideas where to download the latest version from jboss el ? what i found from google search is the to download the latest i should download seam 2 and use jboss inside it : https://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBoss%20Seam/2.3.1.Final/

Comment: You need don't need jboss-el specifically, you need an el implementation. And like posted, websphere provides one out of the box.